# Is this a complete list of the assumptions of linear mixed-effects models?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, assumptions

Crawley (2012) p682 writes:

> There are five fundamental assumptions of linear mixed-effects models:
>
> - Within-group errors are independent with mean zero and variance $σ^2$.
> - Within-group errors are independent of the random effects.
> - The random effects are normally distributed with mean zero and covariance
>     matrix $\Psi$.
> - The random effects are independent in different groups.
> - The covariance matrix does not depend on the group.

My main question is whether this constitutes a complete list of assumptions of linear mixed models. I am talking here about assumptions that are specific to linear mixed modelling. I am aware that each level of the mixed model corresponds to its own regression with its own set of assumptions, e.g. additivity, linearity, independence, equal variance, normality. Are there any other assumptions specific to linear mixed modelling, whether "fundamental" or not, that have been omitted?

My other question is: what's the relevance of specifying variance $σ^2$ and covariance matrix $\Psi$? Is that meant to indicate that we're placing some specific assumption on the form of $\Psi$? What about $σ_{2}$?

Crawley, M. J. (2012). The R book. John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: A linear relationship?

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that you mean assumptions in addition to those that apply to linear models without random effects.

Comment: Good point. I've edited the OP to clarify this.